# Android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS

Tags: android

I tried to import my final APK file to the Google Play Store. I received this error instead:

> Failed to import.
>
> You must use another version code for your APK file, because another file already contains version 1 code.
>
> Your APK uses permissions that require privacy policies: (android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS).

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="berb.coyoterunner"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"> 

     <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity
            android:name="berb.coyoterunner.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

     <!-- Ads Using Google Play Services SDK -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

     </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: What don't you understand of "_Your APK uses permissions that require **privacy policies**_". You either have to tell Google (and your users) why you want these permissions ([see this Google page](https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/privacy-policy-guide)) or you need to stop asking for those permissions.

Comment: How can i add it please

Comment: If you mean "How do I add a privacy policy" then I don't know beyond what it says in the link in my first comment -- either hunt around the rest of the Google developer site and/or search for how to add a privacy policy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to change your version code to 2 for example?

```
    android:versionCode="1" -> becomes 2
    android:versionName="1.0"> -> becomes 1.0.1 or 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should change your version code to a higher number. You cannot upload using the same version code

```
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1">
```

Secondly since you are using these permissions Google has made it mandatory to upload a privacy policy at the time of publishing your app.